# JQuery Sub Selector question

Tags: jquery

my html

```
<div id="x">
  <div id="x1">
    some text
    <div>other text</div>
  </div>
  <div id="x2">just text</div>
<div>
```

my call

I have this element than can be any jquery selector, 1 or more elements:

```
var x = $("#x");
```

now I NEED (this is a plugin who will discover inner elements like tabs) to navigate only thru the firsts DIV elements and not its childrends. I'm trying...

```
$.each($($("div"), x), function() {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

shows:
1. some textother text
2. other text
3. just text

```
$.each($($("div"), x).siblings(), function() {
  alert($(this).html());
});
```

shows:
1. just text
2. some textother text

this is the most approximate, but I need in the correct order. any suggestion ? thanks

ps. because it's a plugin I cant do this.

```
$("#x", "div....")
```

I need to do this

```
#(newselector, x)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you cannot use `$("#x > div")` because it should work with all selectors you think of then assuming you defined that specific selector to var x:

```
var x = $('#x');

// this will select only the direct div children of x whatever the x is
x.children('div');
```

Comment: This is what I need. Thanks. Never saw $().children before.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$("#x > div")
```

as your selector - it will only select the direct children of the `div` whose id is `x`.

Comment: Hi buddy, I said I cant use $("#x") because this is a plugin and $("#x") can be any type of selector, it can be $("*").
It must be done with $(selector, jqueryobj)
thanks.

Comment: @Rodrigo: The answer is still `>`.  You can use it in other ways like `$('> div', jqueryobj)`

Answer (score 1):

This method will give you the all the internal text of a div:

```
x.children('div').each(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

If you don't want *all* the text combined from multiple child divs, you could access only the direct text node of each:

```
x.children('div').each(function() {
  alert(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue);
});
```

Note:  assuming `x` is a Jquery element defined by `var x = $('#x')`.